# Chart.js annotation two vertical line on time axis and two different color

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-annotation

What could be the possible reasons for the vertical line not appearing on the graph despite searching for mistakes in the code and adding the annotation plugin? Additionally, how can two different colors be used to represent values above and below a blue line on the graph?

[image]

Below is my code for the graph:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.2/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.1.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/2.1.2/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js" integrity="sha512-9hzM/Gfa9KP1hSBlq3/zyNF/dfbcjAYwUTBWYX+xi8fzfAPHL3ILwS1ci0CTVeuXTGkRAWgRMZZwtSNV7P+nfw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>


  var ann1  = [current_date_var, end_date_var ];
            var ann_labels1 = ["start", "stop"];
            var annotations_array1 = ann1.map(function(value, index) {
                return {
                    type: 'line',
                    id: 'vline' + index,
                    mode: 'vertical',
                    scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                    value: value,
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    label: {
                        enabled: true,
                        position: "bottom",
                        content: ann_labels1[index]
                    }
                }
            });
            const annotation11 = {
                type: 'line',
                scaleID: 'x',
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderColor: 'black',
                value: current_date_var,
                label: {
                    rotation: 'auto',
                    content: 'Line at x=5',
                    display: true
                },
            };

            const annotation21 = {
                type: 'line',
                scaleID: 'x',
                borderWidth: 3,
                borderColor: 'black',
                value: end_date_var,
                label: {
                    rotation: 'auto',
                    position: 'start',
                    backgroundColor: 'black',
                    content: 'Line at x=90',
                    display: true
                }
            };
            var optionsTwo = {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ['2023-02-15', '', '', '', '', '2023-02-15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2023-03-15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2023-03-31'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Current',
                        data: [0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, '60.00', NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, '70.00', NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN],
                        tension: 0.2,
                        spanGaps: true,
                        backgroundColor: colorcoderedgreen,
                        borderColor: colorcoderedgreenborder,// add fill color here 'rgb(146,239,158)' 'rgb(192,75,75)'
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        segment: {
                            borderColor: ctx => skipped(ctx, 'rgb(0,0,0,0.2)') || down(ctx, 'rgb(192,75,75)'),
                            borderDash: ctx => skipped(ctx, [6, 6]),
                        },
                        spanGaps: true
                        ,fill: '+1'
                    }, {
                        label: ' ',
                        fill: false,
                        data:  [0, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 63.63636363636363, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 100],
                     
                        backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 50, 150)',
                        borderColor: 'rgb(0, 50, 150)',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        segment: {
                            borderColor: ctx => skipped(ctx, 'rgb(0,0,0,0.2)') || down(ctx, 'rgb(192,75,75)'),
                            borderDash: ctx => skipped(ctx, [6, 6]),
                        },
                        spanGaps: true
                    }]
                },
                plugins: {
                    annotation: {
                        annotations: {
                            annotation11,
                            annotation21
                        }
                    }
                },
                options: {
                 /*  annotation: {
                        drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
                        annotations: { annotation11,
                       annotation21}
                    },*/
                   /* annotation: {
                        annotations: [{
                            type: 'line',
                            mode: 'vertical',
                            scaleID: 'A',
                            value: '2023-05-15',
                            borderColor: 'rgb(75, 0, 0)',
                            borderWidth: 4,
                            label: {
                                enabled: false,
                                content: 'Test label'
                            }
                        }]
                    },*/
                    maintainAspectRatio: true,

                    elements: {
                        point: {
                            radius: 0,
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: 'bottom',
                        display: false,
                    },
                }
            }
 
            var ctx1 = document.getElementById('mychartcanvas').getContext('2d'); 
            const chartz = new Chart(ctx1, optionsTwo);
```

Comment: It seems that the "value" option set to annotations are consistent. Having a look to your code, current_date_var and end_date_var should be strings.

Comment: I have passed it as strings..

Comment: May I ask to provide the values of those strings? Annotation plugins on category axes can work by value or by index. The config sounds ok therefore the only thing can be the value passed.